# How to increase the size of points in legend of ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have thousands of points in one figure and set `size = 1`. However, the point size in the legend is reduced too. How to increase the point size in the legend?

For example.

```
num <- 10000
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1, num), y = runif(num), z = rep(1:2, each = num / 2))
df$z <- factor(df$z)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z)) + geom_point(size = 1)
p
```

[image: The size of points in legend]

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Add a `+ guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=10)))` to the plot. You can play with the `size` argument.

Comment: For reference when you want to play a bit more with the settings, see the [online ggplot2 documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html)

Comment: How do I change the size of `color` and `shape` separately in my legend? Trying the following: `guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=2))) +   guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4)))` produces the warning: `Warning message:
In guide_merge.legend(init, x[[i]]) : Duplicated override.aes is ignored.`

Comment: @theforestecologist - you can do this by manually editing individual components of a plot using the `grid` package. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34304453/3174566).