# ggplot reduce line weight in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to control a plot using ggplot2

Sample Script:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(
     sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
     time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
     total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)
p = ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=sex, y=total_bill, group=time, shape=time, color=time)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Now I want to control how the shape and line looks like in the legend. I want a bigger shape, and thin line in the legend. But I can not perform the both.

If I do,

```
p = p + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5)))
```

Both line and shape are thick, similar to Fig B.

If I do,

```
p = p + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5,linetype=0)))
```

Then shapes appear at correct size, but line disappears (Fig A). I tried something like this unsuccessfully.

```
p = p + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5,linetype=0.5)))
```

[image: Example]

How to achieve a big shape and thin line in the legend?

Comment: As far as I know, not with regular ggplot2 commands. But have a [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007324/can-ggplot2-control-point-size-and-line-size-lineweight-separately-in-one-lege/34304453#34304453).

Comment: bit of a hack but... add an extra geom_point and tweak the alpha ... `geom_point(size=5, alpha=0) + geom_point(show.legend=FALSE) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1)))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks [Sandy Muspratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419994/sandy-muspratt) and [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650). Both the link was very useful.

I went with user20650's code just for simplicity.

Complete code here:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(
    sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
    time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
    total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)
p = ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=sex, y=total_bill, group=time, shape=time, color=time)) 
p = p + geom_line() + geom_point(size=5, alpha=0) + geom_point(show.legend=FALSE) 
p = p + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1)))
```

Thanks.