# Display line type correctly in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame and plot. In the plot's legend, the point's shapes are not displayed and the lines are too thick. Is there a way to fix this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)

x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
group <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 25)
dat <- data.frame(x,y,group)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, shape=group, color=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_encircle(data=subset(dat, group=='A'), aes(x=x,y=y),size=2, linetype=2) +
  geom_encircle(data=subset(dat, group=='B'), aes(x=x,y=y), size=3, linetype=3) +
  geom_encircle(data=subset(dat, group=='C'), aes(x=x,y=y),size=4, linetype=4) +
  geom_encircle(data=subset(dat, group=='D'), aes(x=x,y=y))
```

[image]

Comment: `?guides` / `?guide_legend` (hint `override.aes`) :: also, #ty for giving `ggalt` a spin!

Comment: Could you provide an example? I don't understand how these are used.

Comment: If you simplified your call to: `ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, shape=group, color=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_encircle(aes(size=group, linetype = group)) + scale_size_discrete(breaks=c("A" = 2, "B" = 3, "C" = 4, "D" = 1))` would this get you what you want? The line size isnt shown, but the color and point type are

Comment: Yes, that basically does it! Is there a way to make the shapes in the legend slightly larger?

Comment: @Adam_G unfortunately this is quite difficult (but doable): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007324/can-ggplot2-control-point-size-and-line-size-lineweight-separately-in-one-lege

Comment: Got it. Thank you. If you want to make your comment above into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than play with sizing all in the same legend, it might be easiest to split out your shape and line type into different legends. Not exactly what you were looking for, but I think it looks good.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)

x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
group <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 25)
dat <- data.frame(x,y,group)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, shape=group, color=group)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_encircle(aes(size=group, linetype = group)) + 
  scale_size_manual(values=c("A" = 2, "B" = 3, "C" = 4, "D" = 1)) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = 'Shapes') +
  scale_color_discrete(name = 'Linetypes') +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = 'Linetypes') +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 3)),
         linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)),
         size = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm'),
        legend.box = 'horizontal')
```

[image]

Comment: Good effort... colors are used for both linetype and shapes, but this is not reflected in the legend...