# How can I change the colour line size and shape size in the legend independently?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a line plot where I combine a colour and shape into the same legend. I want the dot size in the legend to be larger and the line in the legend to remain the same so that the shape is more clear.

From [How to increase the size of points in legend of ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415963/how-to-increase-the-size-of-points-in-legend-of-ggplot2) I understand that the dot size can be changed with `+ guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=10)))`, however this also changes the line size. If I add `guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4)),color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=1)))` it says `Duplicated override.aes is ignored and only the second size is used.

How can I change the colour line size and shape size in the legend independently?

Example code:

```
example <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), b=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6), c=c('a','a','a','b','b','b'))

ggplot(example, aes(x=a, y=b, color=c, shape=c))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  scale_colour_manual(name="title", breaks=c("a","b"),
                      labels=c("label1","label2"),
                      values=c("#e41a1c", "#377eb8"))+
  scale_shape_manual(name="title", breaks=c("a","b"),
                     labels=c("label1","label2"),
                     values=c(15, 16))+
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4)),
         color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=1)))
```

[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TJPn.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `layer()` function that ggplot uses under the hood has a `key_glyph` argument that you can provide a custom function to. You can use this to make the points larger, but not the lines. If you need custom line adjustments, you can write a similar function wrapping `draw_key_path()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

example <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), b=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6), c=c('a','a','a','b','b','b'))

large_points <- function(data, params, size) {
  # Multiply by some number
  data$size <- data$size * 2
  draw_key_point(data = data, params = params, size = size)
}

ggplot(example, aes(x=a, y=b, color=c, shape=c))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(key_glyph = large_points)+
  scale_colour_manual(name="title", breaks=c("a","b"),
                      labels=c("label1","label2"),
                      values=c("#e41a1c", "#377eb8"))+
  scale_shape_manual(name="title", breaks=c("a","b"),
                     labels=c("label1","label2"),
                     values=c(15, 16))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>